# UIPanGesture Movie Control Laggy

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that plays a video. I want to control the video by Gesture i.e. left-to-right for forwards and right-to-left for backwards.

I have been working with a UIPanGesture and it's allowing me to advance the video with a left/right pan gesture. The only issue is that it's very slow, and doesn't advance the video very often; despite my NSLog firing loads of times per second (depending on the speed and time of the gesture).

Here is my code for the gesture handler:

```
- (void) handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan{

    CGPoint translate = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat xCoord = translate.x;
    double diff = (xCoord - currentTranslate);
    currentTranslate = xCoord;
    NSLog(@"%F",diff);

    if (diff>=0) {
        //If the difference is positive
        moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime = [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime] + (diff/10);
    } else {
        //If the difference is negative
        moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime = [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime] - (diff/10);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here now, how do I make this function smooth and control the playhead in a less laggy manner?

Comment: The perceived speed/responsiveness of a seek depends a lot on the content itself. Is that movie possibly streamed or is it a local file? Does seeking with the "normal" MPMoviePlayerController seek-control behave any different?

Comment: It's a local file, not terribly large. I'll test the seeking behaviour and throw you an update.

Comment: @Till thanks mate, it is the video file. Is there a recommended setup for videos? Playing the video isn't bad, it's just seeking. If you help me and drop it into an answer, I'll mark you as correct.

Comment: I am trying to implement the exact same thing, and got the same problem. Have you found any solution yet? Which setup for the video have you used?

Comment: @EnzoTran eventually, I converted the video to a JPEG stream and rotated through the 'frames' with the pan gesture. A large workaround, but still effective.

Comment: OK thanks, I might need to go down that road too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use FFMPEG for encoding the video files. From my experience, its results are superior to any other solution (a fact that I thought was bizarre).

When it comes to seeking, make sure the GOP-length of your encodings is not set too high. A large GOP makes encoding more efficient but also makes seeking hard for the decoder. In other words, the more I-frames your encodings have, the smoother you will be able to seek around.

For some general parameters on encoding video's for use on an iPhone, see the [ffmpeg cheat sheet by Rodrigo Polo](http://rodrigopolo.com/ffmpeg/cheats.html).

For some details on the mighty power of FFMPEGs parameters when encoding H264, see [the libx264 mapping and options guide](http://help.encoding.com/idx.php/16/126/article/libx264.html).